# Tizen TV - Cache Image (xamarin.forms)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, tizen, tizen-studio, xamarin.tizen

Anyone got an idea of how to cache images on xamarin forms (TIZEN TV)? Tried with FFImageLoading, but it got a dependency to libevas.so1, which is not allowed.

Comment: writing your own should be fairly simple

Answer (score 0):

Plz, visit this page: https://developer.samsung.com/tv/support/documentation-qa/tizen-net-tv-applications-qa#tizen-net-tv

and, refer to No.3 for more detailed information.

Comment: the link goes 404.

Comment: I think.. it is changed to https://developer.samsung.com/SmartTV/develop/support/documentation-qa/tizen-net-tv-applications-qa.html

Comment: Regarding FFImageLoading with Tizen Xamarin.Forms: https://developer.samsung.com/tizen/blog/en-us/2019/12/16/image-caching-using-ffimageloading

Comment: In case of TV, 6.5 platform TV will be available.